# Let TextView fit in Actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar-compat

I got an v7 support `ActionBar` with 3 icons and a `TextView`. The `TextView` is between the icons. If the `TextView` width is to long, the icons on the right are pushed out of the screen. The `TextView` is using a marquee effect, so if the `TextView` is to small for the text there is no problem. I now  need to get the free space in my `ActionBar` and than set it as the `TextView` width like:

```
int freespace=actionbar.getFreeSpace();
textview.setWidth(freespace);
```

Or is there an easier way to prevent the `TextView` to be to big?

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the width of a `TextView` like this.

Create a new LayoutParams object and assign it to your textView :

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f);
textview.setLayoutParams(params );
```

The last parameter of the LayoutParams constructor is the **weight** and allows you to fill the available space with the `TextView`.

Comment: So, I set the weigth of the TextView to 1, but how can I set the weight of the MenuItems? Or am I missunderstanding something?